# Argument 2: Cannot convert from Expression<System.Func<T, bool>> to "System.func<T, bool>"

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am implementing MongoDBRepository using [this](https://github.com/arcnetdev/Arcnet.MongoDB.Framework/blob/master/Repository/MongoRepository.cs) code as a reference but it is giving me an error.

Here's my sample code.

```
   public static IMongoCollection<Book> Initialize()
        {
                MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
                settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress(host, 10255);
                settings.UseSsl = true;
                settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings();
                settings.SslSettings.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
                MongoIdentity identity = new MongoInternalIdentity(dbName, userName);
                MongoIdentityEvidence evidence = new PasswordEvidence(password);
                settings.Credentials = new List<MongoCredential>()
            {
                new MongoCredential("SCRAM-SHA-1", identity, evidence)
            };
                MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);
                var database = client.GetDatabase(dbName);
                var bookCollection = database.GetCollection<Book>(collectionName);
                return bookCollection;
        }
  public Task<IEnumerable<Models.Book>> GetBooksAsync(Expression<Func<Models.Book, bool>> predicate)
        {
            if (predicate == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("Predicate is Null"); }
            var client = Initialize();
            return client.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
        }
```

It shows red underlines under the predicate in the last line of code. The error message shows:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<BookProfile.Models.Book, bool>>' to 'System.Func<Book, bool>'
```

Could someone explain what's the cause of this problem?

Comment: Do you have multiple definitions for `Book`? Try changing the GetCollection to `Models.Book`.

Comment: Well, multiple classes or structs called "Book" where `Book != Models.Book`. I ask because when I try the same thing using my class instead of Book, the only error I get relates to not calling `.AsEnumerable()` and returning a `Task`.

Comment: @john yes thats it! Thank you!!